# Problem with output token from Uniswap's function swapExactTokensForTokens

Tags: solidity, uniswap, sushiswap

I built a bot (with solidity) that swaps on Uniswap and Sushiswap some WETH for another token and viceversa.  In my scripts and in the Uniswap swap UI if i swapped `562 COMP` i would get `10.43 WETH`. I tried to execute the transaction on the ethereum mainnet but when i looked it up on tenderly and i saw that the output token was everything after the 10. So if for Example on the UI the output token would be `10.438338356632642... WETH` (or `10438338356632642... WEI`)the `swapExactTokensForTokens` uniswap function on my bot would return `438338356632642... WEI`. **My question was, why it isn't returning me `10438338356632642... WEI` but instead it returning me `438338356632642... WEI`?**

**The Uniswap UI**
[image]

**My scripts**
[image]